# Maths for finding out when the bottom of the window is at an element

Tags: jquery

So I am trying to create an event when an element is at the bottom of the window. Of course window sizes could be anything, so I am struggling here on how to work this out.

My current code goes like this, but doesnt really take into account any window size:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    win_height = $(window).height();
    scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    pos = $('#home_process').offset().top;
    height = $('#home_intro_bg').height();
    //$('#header_logo').html(win_height+' '+scroll+' '+pos+' '+height);
    if(scroll > win_height-height) {
        $('#home_process_steps li').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

I want a code that essentially says this:

if #home_process becomes viewable within the window - do an action.

How can I work that out?

Comment: Show your simplified markup, please. Better, add it to a fiddle and include it in your question.

Comment: Please try my code. If its not working , please add a comment

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport (viewport selectors for jquery)

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var $elem = $("#home_process");
    var $window = $(window);

    var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

    var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    if((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop)){
        alert(11)
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/yemhv302/4/)